# cannot locate Apache MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache, directory

The title says it all.

I was reading an article about Apache and found this directive, that I cannot locate.

I am using Windows 10 home edition and Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) with PHP/7.2.0beta3.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This directive is not available for Windows.
The only mpm module available for Windows is [Apache MPM winnt](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_winnt.html). However the [MaxRequestWorkers Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) is not available for this module.
If you want to tune your configuration use [ThreadsPerChild](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild) and [MaxConnectionsPerChild](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxconnectionsperchild) directives.

Comment: Yes, I know about the combination of ThreadsPerChild - MaxConnectionsPerChild, but there is a MaxRequestWorkers directive in the `httpd-mpm.conf` file, in `C:\Apache24\conf\extra`. This is there as a template and not to be used in Windows, or I ca use it along with ThreadsPerChild and  MaxConnectionsPerChild ? Thanks